# how to make app-root component to wait for a service to initialize its variables?

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6. In the app-root component, I am injecting LanguageService in the constructor of this app-root component as the following:

```
constructor (private router: Router, private languageService: LanguageService) { }
```

This LanguageService will access local storage and initialize some variables in its constructor. The problem is that whenever I am trying to access any of these variables in app-root constructor I got undefined value. so I tried angular lifecycle hooks such as AfterViewInit as the following:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, private languageService: LanguageService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.router.navigate([this.languageService.language]);
  }
}
```

But the problem still exists. How can I make the app-component wait until LanguageService finishes executing its constructor so that this line:

```
this.languageService.language
```

will not return undefined

**Update:**
here is the constructor of Language Service:

```
constructor() { 
  let _language = localStorage.getItem(`pref_lang`);
  if (_language == null) {
    this._language = 'en';
  }
}
```

Comment: show `languageService` constructor

Comment: The only solution came to my mind is to initialize those variables in the app-root component and in the language service also, but I believe this is very tedious and inefficient.

Comment: That constructor is not asynchronous, so it should always be set... That said, it seems your setting `this._language`, and trying to get `this.languageService.language` (without the underscore)

Comment: Your service constructor uses this._language and in the component you refer to this.languageService.language, how will this work? It should be this.languageService._language

Comment: Vinod Bhavnani I am using getter and setter for a variable of _language so this is definitely not the problem. But yes I found the problem. I noticed when Sachila Ranawaka asks for the code of constructor a couple of errors. I found out I forgot the this keyword for first and second line of the constructor.

Comment: Are you looking for APP_INITIALIZER? take a look to, e.g.,https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the constructor of the language service.

```
let _language = localStorage.getItem(`pref_lang`);
```

should be

```
this._language = localStorage.getItem(`pref_lang`);
```

and

```
if (_language == null)
```

should be

```
if (this._language == null)
```